# Defining a class method in another file

Tags: c++, winapi

I know how to define a class method inside of the same file with which the class is in.

For example:

```
class Robot
{public:
 int location;

 void Moves(); //Class method to be defined
}

void Robot::Moves()
{//Method definition here }
```

I do NOT know hot to define a class outside of the file in which the class is in. I tried creating a .hpp file and defining a class method inside of it, but my compiler signified that it could not load a class definition from a file other than the one the class was created in, or it would be as though I was placing a function's definition before the include directives.

**Please note:** The original class file is also in a .hpp file, as I have yet to learn how to use .cpp files other than the main one.

*This is done using C++/Win32*.

Comment: Put the function in a cpp and link it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a .cpp file along these guidelines

- Include your class header file in your .cpp file
- Include all necessary headers you would use in main.cpp
- use the scope operator for your class

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include "foo.hpp"

foo::foo()
{
//    code here
}

void foo::OtherFunc()
{
//    other stuff here
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you. (I will accept your answer in 9 minutes, as it won't let me accept right now due to just making this post)

Comment: You don't necessarily want all the header files you would use in main. Taking your example here, if `foo` never needs to use anything from `iostream` then you shouldn't include it here. Only include what you need.

Comment: @pstrjds That would be why i included 'necessary headers' in my bulletin. I used the main.cpp reference to give him an example of what i was talking about so he could easily understand.

Comment: @Need4Sleep - I guess it was the way I was reading that. I read it as "include all the headers that were necessary in main.cpp" You can have the +1 now :)

Answer (score 1):

Just put your definition in a .cpp file and link it with your application.

Robot.hpp:

```
class Robot
{public:
 int location;

 void Moves(); //Class method to be defined
}
```

Robot.cpp:

```
#include "Robot.hpp"

void Robot::Moves()
{//Method definition here }
```